# How to parse date return from Facebook feed (JSON)

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api, datetime

I'm calling the following:

`https://graph.facebook.com/ZZZZ/feed?access_token=ZZZZZ&limit=4&`

JSON returned includes

`created_time": "2012-12-13T04:14:29+0000"`

How can I parse and format the date returned into something more friendly? (i.e. 3pm, Tues 3 March)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was to use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) library and parse like so

```
    var date_parsed  = moment(fb.created_time, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm Z");
    var date_display = a.format("MMM Do YYYY, h:mm a");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var ms = Date.parse("2012-12-13T04:14:29+0000");
```

It will give you the amount of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, midnight.

If you want a date object, you can put the output in the `Date` constructor, like so:

```
var ms = Date.parse("2012-12-13T04:14:29+0000");
var date = new Date(ms);
```

Comment: what does it exact mean of this datetime (2012-12-13T04:14:29+0000)?